# load tinymce full mode

Tags: html, tinymce

i uset tinymce plugin in project in last version ( version 4.0b3 ) when use full mode not work and hidden textarea only . but in basic version work right . i used sample code in tinymce page but still notwork . all patch is right too .

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<your installation path>/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    theme: "modern",
    plugins: [
        "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
        "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",
        "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality",
        "emoticons template paste moxiemanager"
    ],
    toolbar1: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image",
    toolbar2: "print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons",
    image_advtab: true,
    templates: [
        {title: 'Test template 1', content: 'Test 1'},
        {title: 'Test template 2', content: 'Test 2'}
    ],
});
</script>

<form method="post" action="somepage">
    <textarea name="content" style="width:100%"></textarea>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you downloaded the "Moxie Manager" plugin.
Check the folder tinymce/plugins/moxiemanager to see if you have the file plugin.min.js

If you do not have the file or the folder moxiemanager itself, then modify the following line

```
"emoticons template paste moxiemanager"
```

to

```
"emoticons template paste"
```

Hope this helps